# Include Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) in Wordpress the_content()

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I've inherited a project structure that uses front-page.php to render the home page. Most of the site uses the Wordpress content field, but we've switched to building new features with Advanced Custom Fields. the_content() is used throughout the codebase to render content, and I'm wondering if there is a way to include ACF layouts in the_content().

An example workaround I've had to use for the homepage is below, if I  don't call the layout in this way content won't render on the page. I'm new to ACF, so if what I'm describing is a fundamental misunderstanding of how to bring ACF into an ecosystem I'd appreciate any guidance on better file structures and calling content.

```php
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
    if (is_page('Home')) {
?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
        <?php
            get_template_part('/layouts/home');
        ?>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
    } else {
        the_content();
    }
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ACF in addition to the original "the_content()" or "get_the_content()" functions. That content comes from the default block or WYSIWYG editor.  ACF comes from additional fields that you add to your pages or posts.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
    if (is_page('Home')) {
        $home_acf_field = get_field('field_name_from_home_acf');//this assumes that the ACF field has been added to the home page, because I'm not using the second parameter
?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
        <?php
            get_template_part('/layouts/home');
            echo $home_acf_field;//this could also be placed in "layouts/home"
        ?>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
    } else {
        $acf_field_from_page = get_field('field_name_from_page_acf');
        the_content();
        echo '<div>'.$acf_field_from_page.'</div>';//an example of where this can go
    }
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

You can incorporate ACF in the template part, or in the page itself.  You need to have the ACF field set up in the CMS to be on home or wherever, but then it's as simple as what I showed you to pull it in (my examples were assuming text fields).

You aren't asking this question, but if you are using "front-page.php" as your home page, then why do you need the if statements to show content?  You can use "the_content()" in addition to your ACF fields, especially if it's the content editor from the home page.  Or, you can just hide it (it's an ACF setting).

Note: I wrote this from memory, and didn't test anything, so please excuse any potential typo. :)